# custom framework in xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, frameworks, objective-c-2.0

I would like to create my own framework to hide the implementation of the classes and to be able to re-use the the classes.

Did they add the ability to create these in 4.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Check out the [Introduction to Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1) by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework.html)! link for framework creation in xcode 4.6. its working fine for me